# C++ giving a negative number when I square

Tags: c++, cmath

So I have some code that is supposed to be giving me the points on a parabola but the problem is that when I square the number when it is a negative it gives me a negative back which wont work.

```
#include "TileClass.h"
//#include <cmath> included in other header
// Original equation y=-x^2+4


void Tile::Loc() {
    for (int a = -2; a < 3; a = a + 1) {
        cout << "--- " << a << endl;
        cout << "Pw" << (a << 2) << endl;
        cout << ((a << 2) + 4) << endl;
    }

}
```

output

```
--- -2
Pw-8
-4
--- -1
Pw-4
0
--- 0
Pw0
4
--- 1
Pw4
8
--- 2
Pw8
12
```

Comment: what are your output results?

Comment: @JoeHigley Just up dated it Gives --- -2
Pw-8
-4
--- -1
Pw-4
0
--- 0
Pw0
4
--- 1
Pw4
8
--- 2
Pw8
12

Comment: posted the answer to your problem below

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ operator << is not the square operator. It is the bitshift operator.

Try

```
-(a*a)+4
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

The express a<<2 will shift each bit of a to left by 2, which means a*4
And if you want to get the square of a, you had better use a*a.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't look like you're squaring.  You're left shifting the binary value which is essentially the same as multiplying by 2 per left shift.  So when `a = -2`, doing `(a << 2)` should result in `-8` being displayed.  What you are looking for is the *pow()* function found in the *cmath* library which should be used like this `pow(a, 2);`

Comment: Thanks I got an answer that worked already though. Thanks for the help

Comment: Squaring with `pow` is big misunderstanding as it may produce wrong answer and is much slower then just x*x

Comment: @Logman I agree it's slower for squaring but not necessarily for other powers.  Also the OP's code uses _cmath_ already.  Also I'm not sure why it would give a wrong answer, please elaborate on that for my own knowledge.

Comment: @JoeHigley I have no idea why I think that it was just being weird sorta like how googles calculator returns a negative number when a negative is set to the power of 2

Comment: google calculator does that because the negative is a multiplication and exponents come before multiplication.  To stop that you just need to encapsulate the negative number in perenthasese.  However doing `pow(-2, 3)` should be the same as `(-2)^3`